# Lost as to how to use the Google Admin Directory API using the javascript client lib

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm including this into my html5 app (reduced down)

```
<script>
    function load() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey('API_KEY');
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
            }, function(){
            gapi.client.load('admin', 'directory_v1', function() {
              // Step 5: Assemble the API request
              console.log(gapi.client);
              var request = gapi.client.directory.users.list({
                customer: "my_customer"
              });
              // Step 6: Execute the API request
              request.execute(function(resp) {
                console.log('RESPONSE', resp);
              });
            });

        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
```

I want to access the directory within my google apps account - When I do this using the google api explorer I can get back all of the information I require but doing it via the google api javascript client (which I know is still in beta) I get back an error from the rpc:

`[{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"notFound","message":"Not Found"},{"domain":"global","reason":"internalError","message":"Internal Error"}]},"id":"gapiRpc"}]`

But I know I have the right credentials/scopes etc as the discovery call gives me back this result:

```
{"methods":{"directory.chromeosdevices.get":{"id":"directory.chromeosdevices.get"},"directory.chromeosdevices.list":{"id":"directory.chromeosdevices.list"},"directory.chromeosdevices.patch":{"id":"directory.chromeosdevices.patch"},"directory.chromeosdevices.update":{"id":"directory.chromeosdevices.update"},"directory.groups.aliases.delete":{"id":"directory.groups.aliases.delete"},"directory.groups.aliases.insert":{"id":"directory.groups.aliases.insert"},"directory.groups.aliases.list":{"id":"directory.groups.aliases.list"},"directory.groups.delete":{"id":"directory.groups.delete"},"directory.groups.get":{"id":"directory.groups.get"},"directory.groups.insert":{"id":"directory.groups.insert"},"directory.groups.list":{"id":"directory.groups.list"},"directory.groups.patch":{"id":"directory.groups.patch"},"directory.groups.update":{"id":"directory.groups.update"},"directory.members.delete":{"id":"directory.members.delete"},"directory.members.get":{"id":"directory.members.get"},"directory.members.insert":{"id":"directory.members.insert"},"directory.members.list":{"id":"directory.members.list"},"directory.members.patch":{"id":"directory.members.patch"},"directory.members.update":{"id":"directory.members.update"},"directory.mobiledevices.action":{"id":"directory.mobiledevices.action"},"directory.mobiledevices.delete":{"id":"directory.mobiledevices.delete"},"directory.mobiledevices.get":{"id":"directory.mobiledevices.get"},"directory.mobiledevices.list":{"id":"directory.mobiledevices.list"},"directory.orgunits.delete":{"id":"directory.orgunits.delete"},"directory.orgunits.get":{"id":"directory.orgunits.get"},"directory.orgunits.insert":{"id":"directory.orgunits.insert"},"directory.orgunits.list":{"id":"directory.orgunits.list"},"directory.orgunits.patch":{"id":"directory.orgunits.patch"},"directory.orgunits.update":{"id":"directory.orgunits.update"},"directory.users.aliases.delete":{"id":"directory.users.aliases.delete"},"directory.users.aliases.insert":{"id":"directory.users.aliases.insert"},"directory.users.aliases.list":{"id":"directory.users.aliases.list"},"directory.users.delete":{"id":"directory.users.delete"},"directory.users.get":{"id":"directory.users.get"},"directory.users.insert":{"id":"directory.users.insert"},"directory.users.list":{"id":"directory.users.list"},"directory.users.makeAdmin":{"id":"directory.users.makeAdmin"},"directory.users.patch":{"id":"directory.users.patch"},"directory.users.photos.delete":{"id":"directory.users.photos.delete"},"directory.users.photos.get":{"id":"directory.users.photos.get"},"directory.users.photos.patch":{"id":"directory.users.photos.patch"},"directory.users.photos.update":{"id":"directory.users.photos.update"},"directory.users.undelete":{"id":"directory.users.undelete"},"directory.users.update":{"id":"directory.users.update"}}}
```

Can anyone tell em what I'm doing wrong? I can't see that I'm doing anything wrong, I'm sending the customer parameter, and using the right function within the object in `gapi.client`, it's getting loaded into `gapi.client` as I can see it available to me, it's just erroring when returning

Comment: Can you use Chrome DevTools (or equiv) to see the exact URL that the API call is requesting?

Comment: Yes, but the javascript client goes to an rpc middleman url as far as i can tell, it's not going to the documented API endpoint, and it doesn't for any of it's requests, so it's difficult to track down what the main issue is, hoping that someone from Google picks this up like it says they will on their support page